# Why doesn't the dropdown menu in Django-summernote work?

Tags: django, summernote

So I have a Django application, am using `django-summernote` as editor. Everything works fine in the editor, except for the dropdown menu. No matter how many times I click the downward arrow, nothing changes. Let me show you the codes : 
settings.py

```
SUMMERNOTE_CONFIG = {
    'iframe': True,
    'lang' : 'ko-KR',
    'summernote': {
        'width': '100%',
        'height': '450px',
        'placeholder':'위대한 글은 위대한 첫 문장에서 시작됩니다!',
        'toolbar': [
            ['style', ['style',]],
            ['font', ['fontsize', 'bold', 'italic', 'strikethrough']],  # 'fontname', 'clear', ...
            ['color', ['forecolor', ]], # 'backcolor'
            ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'height']],
            ['insert', ['link']],
            ['misc', ['fullscreen', 'print', 'help', ]], # 'codeview', 'picture' ...
        ],
    },
    'js': (
        '/static/summernote-ext-print.js',
    ),
    'js_for_inplace': (
        '/static/summernote-ext-print.js',
    ),
    'css': (
        '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.40.0/theme/base16-dark.min.css',
    ),
    'css_for_inplace': (
        '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.40.0/theme/base16-dark.min.css',
    ),
    'codemirror': {
        'theme': 'base16-dark',
        'mode': 'htmlmixed',
        'lineNumbers': 'true',
    },
    'lazy': False,
}

BOOTSTRAP4 = {
    'include_jquery': True,
}

SUMMERNOTE_THEME = 'bs4'
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'

# I'm not really sure what brought me these settings below... Might be related to django-summernote?
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    # 'djangobower.finders.BowerFinder'
]

BOWER_COMPONENTS_ROOT = '/PROJECT_ROOT/components/'
BOWER_INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'jquery',
    'jquery-ui',
    'bootstrap'
)

# All the STATIC and MEDIA settings are fine.
```

template

```
...
{% autoescape off %}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-12 input-content">
      {{form.media}}
      {{form.contents|as_crispy_field|safe}}
    </div>
  </div>
{% endautoescape %}
...
```

What do you think is the problem? Everything but the dropdown menu works perfectly fine. Please let me know if you need further info. Thank you very much in advance :) 
+++ 
For your information, these are what I have in my  tag.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js" integrity="sha256-r/AaFHrszJtwpe+tHyNi/XCfMxYpbsRg2Uqn0x3s2zc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

{% load bootstrap4 %}
{% bootstrap_javascript jquery='full' %}
```

Could one of these be the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know several causes that can lead to your problem:

1. Duplicated imports (jQuery, Bootstrap, etc.) in places like `head` tag and `{{ form.media }}`
2. You must call `$("#content").summernote()` and `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()` to initialize

Comment: First thank you very much. I don't think #2 is the cause, since (a) everything works fine in the editor but the dropdown menu, and (b) I've tried ```$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()``` and it didn't work :( -- So I think the cause would be #1, and I have posted(updated) some of the codes I have in my ```head``` tag. Could you please check it out? Thanks. :)

Comment: Are you sure `{% load bootstrap4 %}` and `{% bootstrap_javascript jquery='full' %}` are necessary? You already included the source. So is `BOOTSTRAP4 = {'include_jquery':True,}` from the first code block you provide.